# Call a ps1 file from a sh script

Tags: bash, powershell, git-bash

I have a sh file running that calls a ps1 file in the end sh /test/ps1 . The PowerShell file sends an alert email saying that the script is complete. Not really sure why its throwing syntax error.
Following errors when bash is calling powershell test.ps1

```
./TEST.PS1: line 4: -t: command not found
./TEST.PS1: line 6: =: command not found
./TEST.PS1: line 7: To: command not found
./TEST.PS1: line 8: SmtpServer: command not found
./TEST.PS1: line 9: From: command not found
./TEST.PS1: line 10: Priority: command not found
./TEST.PS1: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./TEST.PS1: line 11: `}'
```

Also I tried to run the following command on bash but hitting errors as well:

```
git send-email  --f from@email.com --t to@email.com --smtp-server ##.###.###. ~/patches/*.patch
```

Comment: `./TEST.PS1` -> `powershell.exe -File ./TEST.PS1`?

Comment: ill give it a try now - thanks

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers , would you be able to provide an example on how to send an email from the bash without having to call the powershell 1 ?

Comment: That depends on what other commands are available. Bash does not have inherent mail-sending capabilities. You need a program like `mailx`, or `bmail`, or `blat` for that. Or a VBScript or PowerShell script.